# if function used to update vaules broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get the value `n` to update but it will not work for some reason. The code I have so far is:

```
if (coloum.Text == "1")
{
    if (i > s1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are " + s1 + " stones left in this column.");
    }
    else
    {
        s1 = s1 - i;
        coloum.Text = "";
        stones.Text = "";
        n = n + 1;
        if  (n == 3)
        {
            n = 1;
            player.Text = "Player " + n;
        }
```

The `if (coloum.Text == "1")` is true so the statement runs and `if (i > s1)` then the message box shows:

```
s1 = s1 - i;
coloum.Text = "";
stones.Text = "";
```

This part is also updated however my `n` value will not update at all.

I have declared `private int n;` at the start

I'm using visual studios 2015 c#

Comment: Can you show whole function where you declared `n` value?

Comment: You need to increment i or decrement s1 OUTSIDE the if block. Your else will never get hit and that's why n isnt changing